# Which Controller was before?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I got TabBar Application with 3 ViewControllers.
Can i know from the ViewControllers's method which ViewContoller was desplayed before (1 or 2)? Or maybe i open VeiwController from some other .xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just creating `@property` in target `VeiwController` and set this @property firstly in viewDidLoad. So i know that firstly this ViewController will appear from TabBar. After that i can change it in some other ViewController's methods, which call some subviews (.xib).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by implementing `UITabBarController` delegate method -

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
}
```

in this you can check for `[tabBarController selectedViewController]` , here `selectedViewController` is the view controller which is currently selected and `viewController` is which is going to be selected.

Comment: But i need to know which controller was selected

Comment: just make a global UIViewController's instance and when you tap on a tab then the above method will call and here set your global var to the value of [tabBarController selectedViewController] and you can check what view controller it is ...

Comment: can you explain how should i do it?